# React/React-router: Go back to the previous component, bypassing changes in same-component URL parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here is how my web app on React works:

-There is a component to list all the contents the user has generated. Let's call this 'List' component.

-In the 'List' component, there is a navigation bar. The selected navigation option will sort/filter the contents the user has generated. The navigation options are passed as URL parameters.

-On the top of the 'List' component, there is a 'go back' button, which will route the user back to the previous component from which the user has landed to the list component. Here I am using useHistory() hook.

-For example, let's say the user been routed to 'list' component with '/list' path, from 'home' component with '/' path. When the user clicks on the 'go back' button, the user will be routed back to 'home' component.

The problem is, it seems that react router remembers all the navigation history within the '/list' path, and will route back to URLs with parameters. For example, instead of routing the user back to '/' path, it will route back to '/list/abc/', '/list/xyz', etc. Understandably, this is bad user experience.

What will be the trick/method to bypass the URL parameters and go straight back to the previous component? Here is the code for top row component that I am using and declaring useHistory() hook.

```
import React from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faChevronLeft } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

function ListTopRow() {

   let history = useHistory();

   return(
    <div className="top_row">
            <div className="goback">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronLeft} onClick={()=>{history.goBack()}}/>
            </div>
    </div>
    );
 }

 export default ListTopRow;
```

Any advice? Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:**
In case anyone is interested, I resolved this issue by storing history length as a state when the component loads, and combine with history.length to do exactly what I intended.:

```
import {React, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faChevronLeft } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

function ListTopRow() {
   const [historycount, sethistorycount] = useState(null);

   let history = useHistory();

   useEffect(()=>{
       sethistorycount(history.length);
   },[])

   return(
    <div className="top_row">
            <div className="goback">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronLeft} onClick={()=>{history.goBack(historycount-history.length-1)}}/>
            </div>
    </div>
    );
 }

 export default ListTopRow;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need back functionality? Isn't redirecting to a particular address more useful to you? Try the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faChevronLeft } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

function ListTopRow() {

   let history = useHistory();

   return(
    <div className="top_row">
            <div className="goback">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronLeft} onClick={()=>{history.push('/')}}/>
            </div>
    </div>
    );
 }

 export default ListTopRow;
```

Hope that I have understood you correctly and this helps.

EDIT: Now I got your point, I'll get back with an answer soon.

Comment: Hey Enchew, thanks for your answer. The point I forgot to mention is that the previous component has an infinite scroll functionality, so when I redirect with history.push, the scroll position won't be retained. history.back() would have been perfect, but each of the URL parameter change is saved in the history. Any suggestions to overcome these issues?

Comment: You could define a custom history stack, in which you add only the paths, that you want to be able to return to. (This could be saved to a new component’s state or redux state) For example when you sort the table, you change the url, but you don’t add it in the stack and when you go to a new page, your .back() button can be used as .push. I believe you want different behavior for the different pages. (Sometimes back, sometimes push). To do so, you could implement such logic so each component defines their own back functionality. Let me know if you need help with implementing that.

Comment: Hi Enchew, building on your answer, I found a very simple solution. Edited my question above to show my solution. Thanks again.